# how to retrieve data from api spec yaml file in python?

Tags: python, yaml

I have api spec file which explicitly defined api version. I want to access api version data from yaml file and return it to one of my endpoints. To do so, I tried to read my yaml file but cannot access and fetch api version data correctly. Perhaps I might defect in my code. Can anyone point me out how to make this right? any possible thought? how can I fetch and retrieve api version programmatically from yaml file in python?

**api spec yaml definition**

here is how openapi spec fiel defined:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
    info:
      title: test REST API
      description: Test REST API
      license:
        name: Apache 2.0
        url: https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
      version: 1.0.0
    servers:
    - url: /api/v1/
      description: test

    paths:
      /about:
        get:
          summary: api System Version
          description: Obtain current version of test api
          operationId: about_get
          responses:
            "200":
              description: About information
              content:
                application/json:
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/version'
            "401":
              description: Authorization information is missing or invalid.
          x-openapi-router-controller: test_server.controllers.default_controller
      /rsession:

    components:
      schemas:
        version:
          required:
          - mayor
          - minor
          - name
          - patch
          type: object
          properties:
            name:
              type: string
            mayor:
              type: number
            minor:
              type: number
            patch:
              type: number
          description: api Version
          example:
            name: api
            mayor: 1
            minor: 0
            patch: 0
```

**my attempt**:

```
import yaml

spec_yaml= 'apispec.yaml'
with open(spec_yaml, 'r') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)

result = {}
for elem in data['info']:
    name = elem.pop('version')
    result[name] = elem

data['apiversion'] = result

print(data['version'])
```

**update: error**

I have this error down below after testing above code:

> `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'`

this is not working for me. any way I can access my api spec yaml file correctly and fetch api version in python function? any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do like this which would give you version from your yaml file:

```
import yaml

spec_yaml= 'apispec.yaml'
with open(spec_yaml, 'r') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)

print(data['info']['version'])
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your yaml has invalid structure. `openapi:` can either have a value here `3.0.0`, or have inner levels indented below it (`info:` in your case). Not both. A simple json equivalent of your yaml is `{openapi:3.0.0 {info:...}}` which is invalid. So remove the indentation from `info:` and the subsequent rows below it

Here's the corrected yaml

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: test REST API
  description: Test REST API
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: /api/v1/
  description: test

paths:
  /about:
    get:
      summary: api System Version
      description: Obtain current version of test api
      operationId: about_get
      responses:
        "200":
          description: About information
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/version'
        "401":
          description: Authorization information is missing or invalid.
      x-openapi-router-controller: test_server.controllers.default_controller
  /rsession:

components:
  schemas:
    version:
      required:
      - mayor
      - minor
      - name
      - patch
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        mayor:
          type: number
        minor:
          type: number
        patch:
          type: number
      description: api Version
      example:
        name: api
        mayor: 1
        minor: 0
        patch: 0
```

Once you have that, see that the version you are looking for is at info -> version

So you simply need,

```py
import yaml

spec_yaml= 'apispec.yaml'
with open(spec_yaml, 'r') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)
print(data['info']['version'])
```